# How to refer to a variable in curly braces for XML attributes?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

In AS3, I can write the following :

```
var message:String = "Hello";
var data:XML = <data>{message}</data>;
```

but how can I reference the variable to format an XML attribute ?

```
var color:String = "#FFFFFF";
var p:XML = <p><font color="{color}">{message}</font></p>;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the double-quote for your attribute and it should work :

```
var p:XML = <p><font color={color}>{message}</font></p>;
```

here your live example :  http://wonderfl.net/c/xxtT

Comment: @Panzercrisis yeah, I was just waiting to pass the 5 minutes minimum delay

Answer (score 0):

This is Flex's syntax :) If you wanna do it in plain old actionscript, use Regex. This will help you build up your expression: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Hehe removing the double-quotes made the trick. This is actually Flex's MXML/data-binding syntax that made me write them in the first place.

Comment: Ah :D very well. I wanted to suggest a printf kind of thing. Good luck on your coding!

Comment: It's not related to Flex (which is a framework) but to E4X notation :)